# Can I find a nonlinear space in which hyperbola looks linear?

Tags: linear-regression

In kernelized linear regression, we transform the covariate coordinates (x) such that the predictor (y) becomes a linear function of the covariates. I wonder if I can find such a transformation that does this for 1/x (which is discontinuous) or any other discontinuous function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you have good reasons to fit across this singularity ?

Comment: The answer is in the question: set $x'=\dfrac1x$.

Comment: Dear Yves, I would normally do that but my friend is convinced. I can not show him what such a coordinate system would look like. (Neither of us is math major).